# How to write a GraphQL type definition for a class whose name ends on Type

Tags: ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

I'm trying to define GraphQL type definitions. As far as I understand a class has to have a type definition named like the class, plus an appended `Type`. I have a class called `CourseType`, which leads me to this type definition:

app/graphql/types/course_type_type.rb

```
module Types
  class CourseTypeType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :title, String, null: true
  end
end
```

When I try to open the GraphiQL site, I see the following error in the rails console:

```
Unhandled to_type_name input: {:Types=>Types::CourseTypeType} (Hash)
```

I assume that the problem occurs because of the class name, ending with `Type`, as I have another class `Course`, with a type definition named `CourseType`, which works fine.

I didn't find any similar error or documentation on this on Google. How do I have to write this correctly? Thank you.

Comment: I had a similar database model but never faced the issue you are referring to here. Can you mention the GraphQL-ruby version you are using?

Comment: Yes @AbhayNikam it's version 1.10.3.

Comment: I'm actually able to get this to run just fine (created a file named course_type_type.rb with that class definition, and added a field to QueryType to retrieve it). Do you have a field in your QueryType for accessing it?